# Why is my new Activity class not being found? I'm in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting the following error:
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: pip.Test

I assume that means that my class Test is not being found in my namespace PIP.  I used to do this a long time ago, and it worked.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong when I attempt to open a second Activity.  Any thoughts on the proper way to do this are appreciated.  I'm writing some examples for Android 8 and am not quite sure what I am missing, so any thoughts are appreciated.  TIA.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "PIP", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        StartActivity(typeof(Test)); // error occurs here
    }
}
```

Here is my Test class:

```
[Activity(Label = "Test", Name = "pip.Test")]
public class Test : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, this does not seem to help.  :-(
I thought that this changed in several versions ago of Xamarin.android.  From reading documentation, the class I want to load should have a name attribute set to "lowercase namespace.ClassName"  That did not seem to work.  I have tried "regular case.ClassName" as well.  I then went to "packageName.ClassName"  In my case, that would be PIP.PIP.Test.  I tried it with the packagename all lower case.  Any more ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Please share your `classes.dex` in your `obj\Debug\android\bin` folder. There shouldn't be a need to change the name. I would guess an issue with this class on the dexlist first.

Comment: I've put my classes.dex file in my dropbox.  <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v398k8i5or35vw3/classes.dex?dl=0">File</a>

Comment: There is no `pip.Test` on this dexlist. Can you share a minimal viable project?

Comment: That is what I figured.  I had also set the attribute [Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)] on the Test class.  No love there.
Here is a link to my simple project https://www.dropbox.com/s/i66vinwp3vqz7yk/PIP.zip?dl=0

Comment: This makes the dexlist for me locally. Can you try to clear your bin/obj folders? I am on VS 2017 15.5.1

Comment: And of course it works now.  :-)

I am guessing that sometimes a clean and rebuild isn't good enough?

Comment: This is a common issue that I'm hoping to resolve in the future as there is too much manual intervention with those folders on Windows. Clean doesn't really do much for it.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jon.  appreciate it.